# Get Type of Apex Components

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, data-types

I need to dynamically create Apex Components. 
I know that there is method `Type.newInstance` that can do it, but one problem seems like I can't get `Type` variable from Apex component.
For example:
`Type t = Type.ForName(String.valueof(new Component.myComponent()));
        return (ApexPages.Component)t.newInstance();`
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Answer (score 0):

Below is a class and a test class for it which contains code that does what you're asking for provided you have a string containing the type of sObject you want to create. Perhaps this will lead you down the path to a solution to your problem, especially if you're looking for the describe called needed.

```
public class DynamicSObjectCreation {
    public static sObject createObject(String typeName) {
        Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(typeName);
        if (targetType == null) {
            // throw an exception
        }

        // Instantiate an sObject with the type passed in as an argument
        //  at run time.
        return targetType.newSObject(); 
    }
```

Test Class

```
@isTest 
public class DynamicSObjectCreationTest {

   static testmethod void testObjectCreation() {
        String typeName = 'Account';
        String acctName = 'Acme';

        test.startTest();
       // Create a new sObject by passing the sObject type as an argument.
        Account a = (Account)DynamicSObjectCreation.createObject(typeName);        
        System.assertEquals(typeName, String.valueOf(a.getSobjectType()));
        // Set the account name and insert the account.
        a.Name = acctName;
        insert a;

        // Verify the new sObject got inserted.
        Account[] b = [SELECT Name from Account WHERE Name = :acctName];
        system.assert(b.size() > 0);

        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, because `ApexPages.Component` doesn't inherited from `SObject`.

Comment: If you have a record Id, the sObject Type can easily be obtained from that. Otherwise, I don't know what to tell you in terms of getting it from the component since most are reusable code that can be used with a variety of objects. So unless you have a running context, I don't know how you could infer the Object Type.